# FactoryGirl doesn't output associations with build_attributes

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, factory-bot, rspec-rails

I'm probably doing something very stupid here, but I can't get a test to pass because `FactoryGirl.attributes_for` isn't outputting a relational field.

Here's my `project` factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :project do
    status 'active'
    loan_amount 5000
    start_date Time.now
    end_date Time.now + 2.week.to_i
    description "Sample Project"
    user
  end
end
```

Here's the test I'm trying to get this test to pass:

```
let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
let(:project_attributes) { FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:project, user: user) }

it 'assigns a newly created project as @project' do
  post :create, { project: project_attributes }
  expect(assigns(:project)).to be_a(Project)
  expect(assigns(:project)).to be_persisted
end
```

This is the output of `project_attributes`:

```
{:status=>"active", :loan_amount=>5000, :start_date=>2015-12-21 12:07:32 -0800, :end_date=>2016-01-04 12:07:32 -0800, :description=>"Sample Project"}
```

This is giving me an error:

```
@messages={:user=>["can't be blank"]}>
```

Any ideas? Why doesn't FactoryGirl output the user when using attributes_for?

Comment: It may be that `attributes_for` doesn't recognize the association. What happens when you do `user_id: user.id` instead?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `:project` factory definition is a bit off. If project `belongs_to` a user, the factory needs to say `association :user`, as in

```
factory :project do
    status 'active'
    loan_amount 5000
    start_date Time.now
    end_date Time.now + 2.week.to_i
    description "Sample Project"
    association :user
end
```

Comment: This still does not output user as part of `FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:project, user: user)` `user` is acceptable shorthand for `association :user, factory: user`

Comment: Try `FactoryGirl.build(:project, user: user).attributes`

Comment: The issue with that is `status` is an enum and now `.attributes` is setting status to `1` causing an error: `'1' is not a valid status`